# Postgresql insert query error

Tags: php, postgresql, insert

I think that is fine but y don't know why doesn't work

result = pg_Exec($conn,"INSERT INTO people (id, firstname, lastname, phone, email) VALUES(DEFAULT, 'DANNY', 'SMITH', '20245644222', 'danny@hotmail.com')");

if (!$result) {echo "An Insert query error occurred.\n"; exit;}

[image]

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings.

Comment: would you mind sharing with the error message with us?

Comment: I dont think `pg_Exec()` exists. There seems to be a function `pg_execute()`, though. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php

Comment: $firstname = $_GET['fn'];
$lastanme = $_GET['ln'];
$cellphone = $_GET['cp'];
$email = $_GET['em'];

$registros = array();

$conn = pg_Connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=crm user=postgres password=Metallica201411");
 if (!$conn) {echo "An database connection error occurred.\n"; exit;}
$result = pg_Exec($conn,"INSERT INTO people (id, firstname, lastname, phone, email) VALUES(DEFAULT, '$firstanme', '$lastanme', '$cellphone', '$email')");
 if (!$result) {echo "An Insert query error occurred.\n"; exit;}